# How to disable or unsee three dots "..." in all HTML classes?

Tags: html, vue.js, visual-studio-extensions

I'm creating a proyect in VueJS and whenever I create a new class in an HTML tag every class shows as class="..."

I kind of dont like that, I don't know if its related to a new extension i've installed or if its something that comes with vue

Comment: I think you have downloaded accidentally in your visual studio, a  extension for tailwindcss, called `"inline fold"`. this one https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=moalamri.inline-fold . try to desactivate it (or configure it if you still need tailwind in projects different than VueJs)

Comment: Hi David, any update of this case, does laaouatni's suggestion work for you? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Laaouatni Anas posted in the comment of this question the problem was relationated with the "inline fold" vscode extension, I din't notice about it when I was following a tutorial in vue so I uninstalled it and now classes appear clearly :)